# How can I easily parse a raw transaction?

Tags: raw-transaction, parser, decoding

In the Bitcoin ecosystem, there are tools like https://blockchain.info/decode-tx to decode a raw transaction. Is there a site that offers the equivalent for Ethereum?

I'm looking for an easy way to parse a raw transaction and make it human readable, without installing a library or broadcasting the transaction.

Comment: any example of a raw hex you would like decoded ?

Comment: For example, "f87a808504a817c800830186a0944f5f1e8029640b873a43c427e9a4f03cf56ec6d8880c7d713b49da00008d48656c6c6f20506172736572211ba0933fb7fa6919ed12116d1dd27aa03029b4753e74c40d29f228b1da29c9bb6d35a0641dc8b9e783fe219a907f20c006da0d6963292a3a026f425500f182732c7b0f" is one I made on a local development network. I can parse it with tools I have, but it would be nice to give it to someone non-technical and allow them to parse it without using tools I've provided.

Comment: @SteveEnix: What tools are you using to parse it?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Here's one https://github.com/ethereumjs  (ethereumjs-abi) but going to have to close this question.

Comment: Why do you have to close it?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa https://github.com/se3000/ethereum-tx is another option, if ruby is your language

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.  [More info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134)

Comment: This is reopened and converted to community wiki: "Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers."

Comment: Oops nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here: https://rawtxdecode.in/. It supports all Ethereum txs types.

Answer (score 1):

It perhaps doesn't meet the "*it would be nice to give it to someone non-technical and allow them to parse it without using tools I've provided*" qualifier, but the [Ethslurp](http://ethslurp.com/) tool may be of use to people with at least some technical knowhow.

(As mentioned in an answer to this very similar previous question: [Symbolic decoding of a transaction for Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7121/symbolic-decoding-of-a-transaction-for-solidity).)

Answer (score 1):

is [ethereumjs-tx-unsign](https://github.com/warren-bank/ethereumjs-tx-unsign) along the lines of what you're hoping to accomplish?

if so.. and you're also interested in obtaining even more information (from the `signature`), then the `unsign()` function in [ethereumjs-tx-sign](https://github.com/warren-bank/ethereumjs-tx-sign) is a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

Circling back on this 4 years later: This is buried in MEW's Send Offline Helper. If you enter in the signed transaction in Step 3 and flip on the "Raw Transaction" switch it will break out the fields for you(Caveat: doesn't give you v,r,s; instead it gives you the from address).

https://www.myetherwallet.com/send-offline-helper