# How to determine the contract method called and with what parameters from a transaction hash?

Tags: transactions, contract-debugging

Suppose I have a transaction hash and it belongs to some transaction which was done on a smart contract. From the hash, how do I determine what was the contract method which was called and with what parameters?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use an explorer.  For example see [this](https://live.ether.camp/account/3aaaf1c542b365e47f13ab62497f020eee45f747) and click on "Invocation data" and you see that function "breakCookie" was called with the name "Roman".  This requires that the author of the contract uploaded their source code, so that names can be determined from the compiled bytecode.

Another way is to look at the [`input` field of the transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) and parse it according to the [ABI](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts).  You will not have the name of the method, but will see the values of the parameters.

Comment: How one parse input field according to ABI? What tools there are available for this?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/how-can-i-easily-parse-a-raw-transaction but generally asking for tools is better done on another site: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource