# Symbolic decoding of a transaction for Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, raw-transaction

I have a Solidity contract source code and a raw transaction (hex) from blockchain. Is it possible for me to decode the transaction to its symbolic format, so I can see what contract methods are called and with which arguments?

Comment: Related (though unanswered): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/how-can-i-easily-parse-a-raw-transaction

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/how-to-determine-the-contract-method-called-and-with-what-parameters-from-a-tran/6931

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://ethslurp.com. It does exactly that. Here's all ~135,000 DAO transactions decoded (and separated by day and function call) as ASCII text files: http://daodeepdive.com/data.html.

Comment: Ethslurp looks like a great tool! But it doesn't appear to do what the OP asked. It pulls transactions off the blockchain, but it doesn't let you input raw transaction data and parse it out. If, for example, you've generated an offline transaction and want to verify it before posting, ethslurp doesn't help you.

Comment: It says the data is 'from the blockchain,' not that it is about to be sent to the blockchain. You're right thought that it works after the fact with JSON received from etherscan.io APIs. We're working, though, on taking the data directly from Parity via RPC. Maybe the OP can clarify. Is it before the fact, or after the fact?

Comment: What I'm looking for myself is something to doublecheck the offline transactions generated in myetherwallet. Ethslurp may not be the right place for that. I'll probably use it for other stuff though; it should really be better known.