# How to decode a raw transaction in Python?

Tags: python, raw-transaction, decoding

I have a raw_tx in hex format which I'm going to broadcast via `eth_sendrawtransaction` JSON-RPC method.

I want to check this raw_tx by decoding it on fields: gas, gas_price, nonce, value, etc.

Some years ago I already did it in JavaScript. Are there any libraries in Python which can do it?

I think it's possible to do it via this library:
https://github.com/ethereum/pyrlp

But I haven't found there a structure of Ethereum tx object.

Comment: Have you tried [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)?

Comment: Which method of web3py do you mean?
I haven't found any methods to decode raw_tx there.

Comment: I meant to ask if you have searched it in general (since you did not mention it at all in your question).

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/how-can-i-easily-parse-a-raw-transaction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Optional

import rlp
from eth_typing import HexStr
from eth_utils import keccak, to_bytes
from rlp.sedes import Binary, big_endian_int, binary
from web3 import Web3
from web3.auto import w3


class Transaction(rlp.Serializable):
    fields = [
        ("nonce", big_endian_int),
        ("gas_price", big_endian_int),
        ("gas", big_endian_int),
        ("to", Binary.fixed_length(20, allow_empty=True)),
        ("value", big_endian_int),
        ("data", binary),
        ("v", big_endian_int),
        ("r", big_endian_int),
        ("s", big_endian_int),
    ]


@dataclass
class DecodedTx:
    hash_tx: str
    from_: str
    to: Optional[str]
    nonce: int
    gas: int
    gas_price: int
    value: int
    data: str
    chain_id: int
    r: str
    s: str
    v: int


def hex_to_bytes(data: str) -> bytes:
    return to_bytes(hexstr=HexStr(data))


def decode_raw_tx(raw_tx: str):
    tx = rlp.decode(hex_to_bytes(raw_tx), Transaction)
    hash_tx = Web3.toHex(keccak(hex_to_bytes(raw_tx)))
    from_ = w3.eth.account.recover_transaction(raw_tx)
    to = w3.toChecksumAddress(tx.to) if tx.to else None
    data = w3.toHex(tx.data)
    r = hex(tx.r)
    s = hex(tx.s)
    chain_id = (tx.v - 35) // 2 if tx.v % 2 else (tx.v - 36) // 2
    return DecodedTx(hash_tx, from_, to, tx.nonce, tx.gas, tx.gas_price, tx.value, data, chain_id, r, s, tx.v)


def main():
    raw_tx = "0xf8a910850684ee180082e48694a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb4880b844a9059cbb000000000000000000000000b8b59a7bc828e6074a4dd00fa422ee6b92703f9200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010366401ba0e2a4093875682ac6a1da94cdcc0a783fe61a7273d98e1ebfe77ace9cab91a120a00f553e48f3496b7329a7c0008b3531dd29490c517ad28b0e6c1fba03b79a1dee"  # noqa
    res = decode_raw_tx(raw_tx)
    pprint(asdict(res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Outputs:

```
{'chain_id': -4,
 'data': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000b8b59a7bc828e6074a4dd00fa422ee6b92703f920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001036640',
 'from_': '0xD8cE57B469962b6Ea944d28b741312Fb7E78cfaF',
 'gas': 58502,
 'gas_price': 28000000000,
 'hash_tx': '0xb808400bd5a1dd9c37960c515d2493c380b829c5a592e499ed0d5d9913a6a446',
 'nonce': 16,
 'r': '0xe2a4093875682ac6a1da94cdcc0a783fe61a7273d98e1ebfe77ace9cab91a120',
 's': '0xf553e48f3496b7329a7c0008b3531dd29490c517ad28b0e6c1fba03b79a1dee',
 'to': '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
 'v': 27,
 'value': 0}
```

Answer (score 7):

Previous answer is great and works but if you want a shorter code using only 3rd libraries, you can do this:

```
import rlp
from eth_typing import HexStr
from eth_utils import to_bytes
from ethereum.transactions import Transaction

def hex_to_bytes(data: str) -> bytes:
    return to_bytes(hexstr=HexStr(data))
```

Then, to decode:

```
txs = rlp.decode(hex_to_bytes("0xf8a910850684ee180082e48694a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb4880b844a9059cbb000000000000000000000000b8b59a7bc828e6074a4dd00fa422ee6b92703f9200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010366401ba0e2a4093875682ac6a1da94cdcc0a783fe61a7273d98e1ebfe77ace9cab91a120a00f553e48f3496b7329a7c0008b3531dd29490c517ad28b0e6c1fba03b79a1dee"), Transaction)
txs.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'nonce': 16,
 'gasprice': 28000000000,
 'startgas': 58502,
 'to': '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48',
 'value': 0,
 'data': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000b8b59a7bc828e6074a4dd00fa422ee6b92703f920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001036640',
 'v': 27,
 'r': 102512530336280383259877025531328105975098228108468048464966947520424071766304,
 's': 6935304604265909542304656854134707256369339281795067289224235008159636921838,
 'sender': '0xd8ce57b469962b6ea944d28b741312fb7e78cfaf',
 'hash': '0xb808400bd5a1dd9c37960c515d2493c380b829c5a592e499ed0d5d9913a6a446'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution by noleto relies on using [pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum), which has been deprecated and can lead to dependency version conflicts (you should use an old version of rlp). Moreover, answers provided so far do not support for [EIP-1559](https://docs.infura.io/networks/ethereum/concepts/transaction-types#eip-1559-transactions) transactions. The most effective solution I've come across is based on [the code found](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account/blob/543514fe7d681da2981a5ed8882e4f647690fc40/eth_account/account.py#L494) in the eth-account lib.

```
from eth_account._utils.typed_transactions import TypedTransaction
from eth_account._utils.legacy_transactions import Transaction, vrs_from
from eth_account._utils.signing import hash_of_signed_transaction
from eth_account import Account
from hexbytes import HexBytes

def decode(raw_tx):
    txn_bytes = HexBytes(raw_tx)
    if len(txn_bytes) > 0 and txn_bytes[0] <= 0x7F:
        # We are dealing with a typed transaction.
        tx_type = 2
        tx = TypedTransaction.from_bytes(txn_bytes)
        msg_hash = tx.hash()
        vrs = tx.vrs()
    else:
        # We are dealing with a legacy transaction.
        tx_type = 0
        tx = Transaction.from_bytes(txn_bytes)
        msg_hash = hash_of_signed_transaction(tx)
        vrs = vrs_from(tx)
    
    # extracting sender address
    sender = Account._recover_hash(msg_hash, vrs=vrs)

    # adding sender to result and cleaning
    res = tx.as_dict()
    res["from"] = sender
    res["to"] = res["to"].hex()
    res["data"] = res["data"].hex()
    res["type"] = res.get("type", tx_type)

    return res
```